# Turn off antialiasing for black and white bitmap Rendered from canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap, antialiasing

I have a problem with WPF's anti aliasing of text.  In my application the user designs text or image fields  to be printed using a special printing device. I am using a canvas to host the fields, which are either textblocks or Images

The problem is when i convert this canvas into a RenderTargetBitmap, then into a black and white FormatConvertedBitmap, the text and images end up extremely fuzzy looking.

I have tried using "snaptodevicepixels = true" and "RenderOptions.EdgeMode" = Aliased on everything in the application.  I know anti aliasing is great for the screen, but printing is a real disaster.

Here is an example of my code:

```
private BitmapSource GetCanvasAsBitmap(Canvas cvs)
  {   
   cvs.Background = Brushes.White;
   RenderOptions.SetEdgeMode(cvs, EdgeMode.Aliased);
   cvs.SnapsToDevicePixels = true;

   // render TopCanvas visual tree to the RenderTargetBitmap

   Size CanvasSize = new Size(cvs.Width, cvs.Height);
   cvs.Measure(CanvasSize);
   Rect CanvasRect = new Rect(CanvasSize);
   cvs.Arrange(CanvasRect);

   RenderTargetBitmap targetBitmap =
    new RenderTargetBitmap((int)cvs.ActualWidth,
     (int)cvs.ActualHeight,
     96, 96,
     PixelFormats.Default);

   targetBitmap.Render(cvs);


   double scale = PIXELSCALE / cvs.Height;
   ScaleTransform ST = new ScaleTransform(scale, scale);

   TransformedBitmap TB = new TransformedBitmap(targetBitmap, ST);

   return TB;
  }



  private static FormatConvertedBitmap Recolor(BitmapSource b)
  {   
   BmpBitmapEncoder encoder = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
   encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(b));

   using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("BeforeRecolor.bmp", FileMode.Create))
   {
    encoder.Save(fs);    
    fs.Flush();
    fs.Close();
   }

   FormatConvertedBitmap FCB = new FormatConvertedBitmap(b, PixelFormats.Indexed1, new BitmapPalette(new List<Color>() { Colors.Black, Colors.White }), 0);

   BmpBitmapEncoder en = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
   en.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(FCB));

   using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("AfterRecolor.bmp", FileMode.Create))
   {
    en.Save(fs);
    fs.Flush();
    fs.Close();
   }

   return FCB;
  }
```

how do i turn off the antiailasing before creating the rendertargetbitmap?

Comment: I'd guess your problem is here: ScaleTransform ST = new ScaleTransform(scale, scale);  It's not the anti-aliasing, its the scaling to a higher-res bitmap.  Try to render to a bitmap with the same DPI as your output device, and don't scale.

Comment: @antlersoft You are right. I should just render it to the right size in the first place. But that hasn't changed the results i am getting. The resulting bitmap of the text is still blurry.

Comment: It defiantly is an anti aliasing problem. The bitmap looks fine (anti aliased of course) after the rendering. But once i do the Recolor the nice clean lines disappear and I end up with a very fuzzy image.

Comment: Well, for anyone who needs the answer. the only way i found was to draw all the text to a GDI+ Graphics bitmap. and then convert that into a bitmap source

Answer (score 0):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dwayneneed/archive/2008/06/20/implementing-a-custom-bitmapsource.aspx

Apparently dither type is hardcoded

> #### FormatConvertedBitmap
>
> This class wraps the standard WIC pixel format
> converter (IWICImagingFactory::CreateFormatConverter).  This component
> provides the means of converting from one pixel format to another,
> handling dithering and halftoning to indexed formats, palette
> translation and alpha thresholding. The Source, DestinationFormat,
> DestinationPalette, and AlphaThreshold properties are used to
> initialize the underlying component via
> IWICFormatConverter::Initialize. **The dither type is hard-coded to be
> WICBitmapDitherTypeErrorDiffusion.**  The palette translation type is
> hard-coded to be WICBitmapPaletteTypeMedianCut. The ISupportInitialize
> interface is used to snap the values of the properties when
> initialization is complete.  Further changes to the properties are
> ignored.

Comment: The provided link does not work anymore. I found the text on github, with an excellent explanation of all the WPF bitmap processing pipeline: https://dwayneneed.github.io/wpf/2008/06/20/implementing-a-custom-bitmapsource.html