# WPF pixelated black and white image after conversion

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I have a wpf app with an `Image Control`. I draw lines and text, display on the image the text fields with different colours based on the `type` of the text.

For this example all colours will be white.

I will then press a button, convert the image to `BlackWhite`, display it to the image control and then I generate a raster file.

The problem i have is that when I convert it to Black & White the shadows around the lines and text are getting `Pixelated`.

> Is there a way to get rid of the shadows or stop them from getting
> pixelated?

I could even do with drawing on an extra hidden BlackAndWhite image at the same time and generating the raster from that image and not the one the user sees.

[image: ExampleImage]
[image: zoomedFinalImage]

### Minimal Workable Example

*xaml*

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="500">
    <Grid>
        <Image x:Name="originalImage" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="30,100,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="183" />
        <Image x:Name="convertedImage" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="250,100,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="183" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

*xaml.cs*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DrawingVisual visual = new DrawingVisual();
            using (DrawingContext dc = visual.RenderOpen())
            {
                int fs = 28;
                string textContain = "Testing 123";
                Point p = new Point(0, 0);
                dc.DrawRectangle(Brushes.Black, null, new Rect(0, 0, originalImage.Width, originalImage.Height));
                dc.DrawText(new FormattedText(textContain, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
                            new Typeface("Arial"), fs, Brushes.White, VisualTreeHelper.GetDpi(visual).PixelsPerDip), p);
            }
            RenderTargetBitmap target = 
                new RenderTargetBitmap((int)originalImage.Width, (int)originalImage.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Default);
            target.Render(visual);
            FormatConvertedBitmap grayBitmapSource1 =
            new FormatConvertedBitmap(target as BitmapSource, PixelFormats.Bgr24, null, 0);

            var grayBitmapSource = new FormatConvertedBitmap();
            grayBitmapSource.BeginInit();
            grayBitmapSource.Source = grayBitmapSource1.Source as BitmapSource;
            grayBitmapSource.DestinationFormat = PixelFormats.BlackWhite;
            grayBitmapSource.EndInit();
            originalImage.Source = target;
            convertedImage.Source = grayBitmapSource;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Without a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, you're unlikely to find anyone willing to spend time on the question. That said: what you call "pixelation" appears to me to simply be anti-aliasing artifacts caused by the thresholding algorithm used when converting to B&W. Try controlling the conversion more carefully, and allowing any non-zero pixel value to be foreground in the B&W image. Alternatively, you can render the text to a path, and then draw that directly into the B&W image instead of converting the original color image.

Comment: @PeterDuniho thanks mate for the heads up. Hope this is ok now. I was thinking about "reading" the image one pixel at a time, before I convert it, and "write" that pixel on another image. If the r or g or b are not zero then paint a black dot on a 1bit bmp image. But I had a quick look and I can't find a way to get the rgb value from the image control and make a 1bpp image (and set a pixel on it)

Comment: The other thing I am exploring now is drawing a System.Drawing.Image along side the original image, and export the raster from that. The problem that I have with this is that the byte array from the drawing.image with memory stream,  is different compared to the original one that I get with CopyPixels (it seems like inverted to me).

Comment: Now that I think about it, I vaguely recall that WPF won't allow 1bpp format for `RenderTargetBitmap`. Which is unfortunate, as that really would be the best way to go. I think that the second-best way is to use `WriteableBitmap` as you suggest, converting pixels directly yourself. Using GDI+ (i.e. `System.Drawing.Image`) is also an option, as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550731/turn-off-antialiasing-for-black-and-white-bitmap-rendered-from-canvas

Answer (score 1):

I think I am on to something. I took the image, made it a gray8 image, wrote that image to an array on which every byte is a pixel. Then using that array I generate another array where each byte is 8 pixels and from that I either generate a final picture.
This image is for comparison:
[image: img1]

And here is the example:

xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="500">
    <Grid>
        <Image x:Name="originalImage" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="30,100,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" />
        <Image x:Name="convertedImage" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="250,39,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" />
        <Image x:Name="CustomConvertedImage" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="250,156,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

## xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DrawingVisual visual = new DrawingVisual();
            using (DrawingContext dc = visual.RenderOpen())
            {
                int fs = 28;
                string textContain = "Testing 123";
                Point p = new Point(10, 10);
                dc.DrawRectangle(Brushes.Black, null, new Rect(0, 0, originalImage.Width, originalImage.Height));
                dc.DrawText(new FormattedText(textContain, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
                            new Typeface("Arial"), fs, Brushes.White, VisualTreeHelper.GetDpi(visual).PixelsPerDip), p);
                dc.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.White, 3), new Point(5, 5), new Point(originalImage.Width - 5, 5));
                dc.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.White, 3), new Point(5, originalImage.Height - 5), new Point(originalImage.Width - 5, originalImage.Height - 5));
                dc.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.White, 3), new Point(5, 5), new Point(5, originalImage.Height));
                dc.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.White, 3), new Point(originalImage.Width - 5, 0), new Point(originalImage.Width - 5, originalImage.Height - 5));
            }
            RenderTargetBitmap target =
                new RenderTargetBitmap((int)originalImage.Width, (int)originalImage.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Default);
            target.Render(visual);
            FormatConvertedBitmap grayBitmapSource1 =
            new FormatConvertedBitmap(target as BitmapSource, PixelFormats.Bgr24, null, 0);

            var grayBitmapSource = new FormatConvertedBitmap();
            grayBitmapSource.BeginInit();
            grayBitmapSource.Source = grayBitmapSource1.Source as BitmapSource;
            grayBitmapSource.DestinationFormat = PixelFormats.BlackWhite;
            grayBitmapSource.EndInit();
            originalImage.Source = target;
            convertedImage.Source = grayBitmapSource;
            CustomConvertedImage.Source = ConvertToBlackAndWhiteAliased(originalImage, 80).Item1;
        }

        private Tuple<System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource, byte[]> ConvertToBlackAndWhiteAliased(Image _sourceImage, int _grayFilter = 80)
        {
            FormatConvertedBitmap grayed8Image = new FormatConvertedBitmap(_sourceImage.Source as BitmapSource, PixelFormats.Gray8, null, 0);
            double bytePerPixel_Test = grayed8Image.Format.BitsPerPixel / 8.0;
            int width_Test = grayed8Image.PixelWidth;
            int height_Test = grayed8Image.PixelHeight;
            int stride_Test = (int)(width_Test * bytePerPixel_Test);
            byte[] resultLine_Test = new byte[height_Test * stride_Test];
            grayed8Image.CopyPixels(resultLine_Test, stride_Test, 0);

            double bytePerPixel = 1 / 8.0;
            int width = grayed8Image.PixelWidth;
            int height = grayed8Image.PixelHeight;
            int stride = (int)(width * bytePerPixel);
            byte[] resultLine = new byte[height * stride];

            byte tempByter;
            for (int enum8bpp = 0; enum8bpp < resultLine_Test.Length; enum8bpp += 8)
            {
                tempByter = 0;

                for (int tempByterEnumer = 0; tempByterEnumer < 8; tempByterEnumer++)
                {
                    tempByter |= (byte)(((resultLine_Test[enum8bpp + tempByterEnumer] > _grayFilter) ? 1 : 0) << 7 - tempByterEnumer);
                }

                resultLine[enum8bpp / 8] = tempByter;
            }
            WriteableBitmap bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(width, height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.BlackWhite, null);
            bitmap.WritePixels(new Int32Rect(0, 0, width, height), resultLine, (int)(width * (bitmap.Format.BitsPerPixel / 8.0)), 0);
            return new Tuple<System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource, byte[]>(bitmap, resultLine);
        }
    }
}
```

You can get either the image from the function (with .item1) or the array directly (item2). _grayFilter is for how sensitive you want the converter to be (0 to 255 for 256 shades of gray in the gray8 pixelformat).
The problem that I have and for some reason (brain is probably like a mush potato because of the lock down) I can't solve it, is that the original image width needs to be dividable by 8 otherwise it throws an exception. I mean I understand why, you need 8 bytes of the original image to make a byte on the second array, but I can't find a way to add nulls. Probably will figure it out tomorrow but feel free to help :)

Comment: _"the original image width needs to be dividable by 8 otherwise it throws an exception"_ -- I haven't bothered to review your new attempt closely. However, typically when you run into problems that go away only at specific widths, you have a problem with your bitmap stride. Either you have not set the stride correctly in the first place, or are not respecting the stride correctly elsewhere. You will typically see different exceptions for the different mistakes (or sometimes no exception and the bitmap will just look wrong).